# Filter Pivot Table for fields containing a value

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, vba

I am trying to filter the pivottable field "name" to only display records that have "AA5" in the title.

When I record the macro, it seems to only de-select the newest items that do not contain AA5 (using the false property).  Rather than using the AA5=true property.

However, since the pivot is constantly updated with new data, running the macro a second time does not remove the newly added items, since the code has identified which NOT to show, rather than which TO show.

```
Sub Macro3()

    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name")
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name")
        .PivotItems("Test:777:1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Test:777:2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Test:777:3").Visible = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It would go this way:

```
Sub Quick()
    Dim PTfield As PivotField

    Set PTfield = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Name")
    With PTfield
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add xlCaptionEquals, , "AA5" 'for exact matching
    End With

End Sub
```

If `AA5` is a part of filtering fields, then change parameter into `xlCaptionContains`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple macro that actually works.  I have a pivot table that contains on Column H Order Fill Rate % of various finished goods.  Order Fill Rate of 98.5% or lower is considered no good.  This macro will go to Column H starting with Row 5 and go down row by row to check the fill rates.  It will hide the rows that are good leaving visible those rows that require futher analysis or action.  It will keep doing this until it reaches the "last row"

Sub zSeries09_FilterPivotTable_ByFillRate98pt5()
'
' zSeries09_FilterPivotTable_ByFillRate98pt5 Macro
'

'
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

```
Dim LR As String

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select

LR = ActiveCell.Row

Application.Goto Reference:="R5C8"
```

Routine:

```
 If ActiveCell.Row < LR Then GoTo TestError Else GoTo EndCom
```

TestError:

```
 If IsError(ActiveCell) = True Then GoTo HideRow Else
```

TestBlank:

```
 If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True Then GoTo HideRow Else
```

TestFillRate:

```
 If ActiveCell.Value >= 0.985 Then GoTo HideRow Else
```

NoHide:

```
 Application.Goto Reference:="R[1]C"

 GoTo Routine
```

HideRow:

```
 Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Application.Goto Reference:="R[1]C"

GoTo Routine
```

EndCom:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

End Sub